# change member of a list that contains only string member

Tags: python, string, list

I have a original list with name 'm' as below :

```
m = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

now, decision maker tells me a list that contains a new group. for example, it says that:

```
['AB']
```

it means that, in my original list, 'A' , 'B' has been merged together. and my new original list member will be

```
['AB','C', 'D', 'E']
```

how can I code this problem in python ?
please halp me to solve it. thanks a lot.
Regards.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Show me how to solve this coding problem" is not a Stack Overflow issue. We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are given the string 'AB' and then want to manipulate the list, you could try the following.

```py
given = 'AB'
m = [i for i in m if i not in given] + [given]
```

Answer (score 1):

another way to do

```
m = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
n = m[0] + m[1]
o = [n] + m[2:5]
print(o)
```